# concat_ws and lowercase and uppercase

Tags: mysql, uppercase, lowercase

I am using `concat_ws` to search a table (code given below).

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE CONCAT_WS('',lastname,firstname) LIKE '%$string%'
```

My problem is that seperates uppercase and lowercase.

If I search AB I get 10 results BUT if I search ab I get 1 result.

Is there any way to get the same results, meaning not separate uppercase and lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE LOWER(CONCAT_WS('',lastname,firstname)) LIKE '%$string%'
```

And search in lowercase ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE LOWER(CONCAT_WS('',lastname,firstname)) LIKE '%$string%'
```

The solution assumes, the `$string` variable is always lowercase.